# Issue with CanCan ability and block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I have problem with cancan. I add role in ability.rb

```
if user
 can :manage, Account do
  (some code which return boolean value). For example: user.verify?
 end
end
```

and on my view for button I add verify

> if can? :index, Article

I see my button all the time irrespective of the result block true or false. Thank you for help

Comment: it's clearly written in the doc the block should not depend on the user since it's not always evaluated

Comment: when I set false value in block, I see same result. do false end. In block I am trying not to depend on variables

Comment: index page do not instantiate any particular article, so the block will never nbe called

Answer (score 0):

If an ability for a class is defined using a block, the block will be ignored when checking on the class. You'll need to check on an instance of the class, like so:

```
if can? :index, Article.new
```